# semi dynamic cdn

Tags: php, wordpress, cdn

i'm developing couple of websites using php (directory script, etc.) and wordpress as cms. i need to improve its performance, by using cdn for static files (css, js, images). the problem is, css and javascript files are generated on the fly. i did that due to yahoo and some expert advice to combine the files into one file. also changing basic color of css files.

for the time being, i use couple of small vps but still its not fast enough. i already contact maxcdn and the support guy said that they dont have such kind of services.
what i need is: a cdn that will serve the request from user/visitor and there's no file in local disk, the cdn will redirect/fetch it from another domain/server.

in vps, it could be done easily using combination of .htaccess and php, but NOT in the cdn. most of cdn only support purely static files.
is there any such cdn that will server semi-dynamic files?

Comment: are you sure that your bottleneck is a static content?

Comment: NO. but i want to make the main server to serving dynamic content only, and cdn for static files. hoping that it will increase my server availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since you asked, but this is something I've been recently investigating as well.  I had a live-chat with VoxCast earlier today and they support a mix of static and dynamic content.

How I believe it works is you set up a server (or use their hosting) and this becomes the 'origin server'.  Then using some server config (Apache, they also provide a mod to assist this) it caches static content as appropriate and leaves other requests to come straight through to your origin server.  You need to be able to differentiate between the static and dynamic content using a regex though.

http://www.voxel.net/voxcast-cdn

Hope that helps.